# Does the SP4 for Windows 2000 Server include a .NET framework?

Tags: windows-server-2000

Was wondering if SP4 installed .NET Framework 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows 2000 doesn't natively include any .NET Framework at any service pack level.

You have to download and install it, manually or via Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not 2.0. I'm not even sure if it included .net Framework 1.1.

SP4 was released late 2003, .net Framework 2.0 in early 2006.